Moving files to a new volume; keeping same Time Machine backup
My desktop (iMac) system includes the internal SSD and an external storage disk; call it 'A'. Both are backed up with Time Machine on another external drive, 'B'. Now, 'A' is getting full. I want to move two folders, X and Y, comprising about half of all the files on 'A', to a new external drive, 'C'. Can I / how can I get Time Machine to continue to use the same backups, on 'B', for X and Y once they are moved to 'C'?
I reckon I could
(1) Copy X and Y from 'A' to 'C';
(2) Include 'C' in the Time Machine backup; That would cause Time Machine to make new backups for X and Y, which is what I'm trying to avoid.
(3) Delete the backup X and Y on 'A' from Time Machine;
(4) Delete X and Y from 'A'.
Seems rather cumbersome -- and time consuming! Total data involved would be about 1TB. Is there a simpler, more direct approach?
